# Matplotlib basemap parallels don't appear in eastern hemisphere when lat_0 < 35 degrees

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I successfully reproduced the example for the azimuthal equidistant project from the Matplotlib website: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/aeqd.html.

However, when I change the `lat_0` parameter from `40` to `35` (with no other changes), the parallels disappear in the western hemisphere (see image below). Is this a bug? Otherwise, how can I fix it?

[image: Azimuthal equidistant projection lacking eastern hemisphere parallels.]

Version information:
Python: 2.7.6
Matplotlib: 1.3.1

Comment: In order to show the parallels correctly with `lat_0=35`, you may use a smaller width, e.g. `width=27000000`. This however, is only a workaround and I don't know what's causing this. Also note that when using smaller `lat_0` values, `width` needs to decrease even further to show the parallels. Even more strangely, when using negative `lat_0`, the continents are drawn wrong. So yes, I guess it's a bug.

Comment: Side note: matplotlib 1.3 is ancient. Can't you update to something newer (2.1?)?